# How to alert if the expire date is close to now date in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, tkinter

I make like a shop market in tkinter, I tried to make a function that send me a `messagebox.showwarning()` If `(date_now - 5_days) == expire_date`

I tried this code in [this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31885821/code-to-check-for-expiration-date-from-one-python-scripts-output) But doesn't works:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
datet = '15-12-2015'

ExpirationDate = datetime.strptime(datet,"%d-%m-%Y").date()
now = date.today()
if (now - 5) == ExpirationDate:
    messagebox.showwarning("Expired item", "This item is Expired")
```

Comment: What does "doesn't works" mean in this context? Do you get an error? Does it show the warning at the wrong time? Something else?

Comment: @BryanOakley No, It just didn't return any value in the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) to define 5 days like:

```
from datetime import timedelta

five_days = timedelta(days=5)
```

You should also fix the if statement, testing for exact equality ignores all dates after the expiration. Why not use **>=**.